# Why is the key dropped when a key column is updated?

Tags: r, data.table

I just noticed a small quirk in the package. See code snippet below to reproduce.

---

```
DT = data.table(a=1:3, b=1:6);
setkey(DT,b);

# As expected - data is "keyed" on b
> key(DT) 
[1] "b"

# Now if i change content of column b, the key on the table "drops out"
DT [,b := seq(1,6)];

> key(DT)
NULL
```

FYI am on `R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16)`, `Platform (x86_64-w64-mingw32)` and `data.table version 1.8.11`.

It seems to me that whenever a key column is updated - the `data.table` code drops the keys off completely since the content of the data (and hence the order of it) changes. I would have expected the code to store the key, change the content of column b, reorder column b and reinstate column b as the key. In short, keep the key unchanged.

This is similar to the behavior you would expect in `RDBMS databases` and `tables`. The key doesn't drop off even if the data content changes.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think of it as a little strange to need to change a key value. It's common to want to add and update new columns alongside the data that's been loaded using `fread` or from a database using RODBC, but it's rare to want to change a value in a key column, isn't it?  The key columns are normally fundamental to the dataset and don't change.

`data.table`'s approach to this is by default it does the fastest thing. It changes the value in the key column as you asked it to do, and then it drops the key because it's not sure if the key is still valid or not. If you *really* want it to rebuild the key, which will likely incur a reorder of the whole table, then just call `setkey` again explicitly. That way, the extra `setkey` in your code will make it clear to readers of your code, that that update to that key column could be expensive.

A key in `data.table` is merely the sort order. It's more akin to a *clustered index* in SQL, where the rows on disk are actually stored in that order.

Comment: Matt - thanks for your reply. Correct, you would not often alter data to a "key" column however there are few handful of exceptions (the problem I am dealing with involves the amend). I was not sure if the community was aware of this behavior hence I thought I would raise the issue. Happy to make a call to setkey again. Thanks Manoj